# Include 0 when using count() SQL Server Left Join not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Here I have used a left join on the person table because I want to include every record in that table even if it doesn't have an associated record in the task table. How can I resolve this to include the 0's in my results?

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR, COUNT(p.personID))                                                  AS count,
       CONVERT(DECIMAL(4, 2), 1.0 * COUNT(p.personID) / DATEDIFF(DAY, @startDate, @endDate)) AS average,
       p.personID,
       p.firstname,
       p.lastname,
       c.companyname
FROM   Tasks t
       LEFT JOIN Person p
         ON p.personID = t.personID
       JOIN Client c
         ON c.id = p.employer
       JOIN Commission m
         ON m.ClientID = c.ID
WHERE  t.created BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
       AND m.owner IN ( 'John Doe' )
GROUP  BY p.personID,
          p.firstname,
          p.lastname,
          c.companyname
ORDER  BY c.companyname,
          count DESC
```

Comment: About `nvarchar` without length: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Comment: Why would you want to convert the count to a `nvarchar` anyway?

Comment: So you left join to person, then you inner join to client. Does this produce the rows you expect it to produce?

Comment: swasheck- I convert the count to nvarchar because I am using crystal reports and it says that it can't convert it from a decimal to an int.

Comment: When you left join to person any non matching rows preserved will have `NULL` for all columns. Then your next inner join removes them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out the answer to my problem... because I put conditions in the where clause on behalf of the other tables that I joined, it filtered out what I wanted. So I changed the person table to the "driving table" and I took the conditions from the where clause and put them in the join statement as I was joining the tasks table as follows:

```
SELECT 
       convert(nvarchar, COUNT(t.personID)) AS count,
       CONVERT(decimal(4, 2), 1.0*COUNT(t.personID) 
                              / DATEDIFF(DAY, @startDate, @endDate)
              ) AS average,
       p.personID,
       p.firstname,
       p.lastname,
       c.companyname
    FROM Person p
    LEFT JOIN Tasks t
       ON t.personID = p.personID AND t.created BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate  
    JOIN Client c 
       ON c.id = p.employer
    JOIN Commission m 
       ON m.ClientID = c.ID AND m.owner IN ('John Doe')     
    GROUP BY p.personID, p.firstname, p.lastname, c.companyname
    ORDER BY c.companyname, count DESC
```

Comment: You probably want to change those `COUNT(p.personID)` to `COUNT(t.personID)`

Answer (score 0):

Provide filtered input through a subquery instead of the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT 
   convert(nvarchar, COUNT(p.personID)) AS count,
   CONVERT(decimal(4, 2),1.0*COUNT(p.personID) / DATEDIFF(DAY, @startDate, @endDate)) AS average,
   p.personID,
   p.firstname,
   p.lastname,
   c.companyname
FROM Person p
LEFT JOIN (
    select personId from tasks
    where t.created BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
) t
   ON t.personID = p.personID   
JOIN Client c 
   ON c.id = p.employer
JOIN Commission m 
   ON m.ClientID = c.ID AND m.owner IN ('John Doe')     
GROUP BY p.personID, p.firstname, p.lastname, c.companyname
ORDER BY c.companyname, count DESC
```

Maybe not the most useful in this particular example, but if the WHERE clause is complex and filtering more than one table, this is the answer.